# How do I get WooCommerce to recreate the home page?

Tags: plugins

I was hoping the answer to the question (How do I get WooCommerce to automatically recreate pages?) would help but i could not recreate the home page.
Im using mystile theme and when i go to customize i cant find the home page to set it as the front page.How can i recover the built in home page ?

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce does not create a 'home page'. The pages which do get auto-created (as part of version 2.0.14 which is stable at the time of writing) are:

1. Shop (this is a placeholder for the main post type archive)
2. My Account
3. Checkout
4. Cart
5. lost password
6. logout
7. edit address
8. view-order
9. change password
10. Pay
11. Order received

To have this pages recreate (again) correctly,

1. Trash and delete the pages from Admin > Pages
2. go to WooCommerce > Settings > Pages, unset the 'Shop base' page option and any others.
3. De-activate, then re-activate WooCommerce. The install page notice will be displayed.

Alternatively, create any page manually and select your page in WooCommerce > Settings > Pages